# better way of floating images in a slider without giving big width to parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below is my code for simple slider(it currently does not work because I have not implemented javascript yet). Right now this slider has 2 images(with different resolution ofcourse). What I did is I `.sliderContainer` I gave width `2520px` and to `.wrapper` I set `overflow` to `hidden`. This is something normal I do with slider or carousal.

Now what would happen if I add an additional image that is the number of images become 4 or 5 or 6 or 20 lets say. Then I will go inside the code and keep changing the width of `.sliderContainer` to make it properly work. Now I need a way where I do not have change the width of `.sliderContainer` everytime but it should happen as new images are added. New images could come from database from server in json object.

**How can I achieve this?**

Below is my code.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="sliderContainer">
  <div class="slider"><img src="http://googleplus-covers.com/covers/nature_balloon_ride.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="slider"><img src="http://p1.pichost.me/640/10/1326822.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="slider"><img src="http://googleplus-covers.com/covers/coludy_mountains_nature.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.sliderContainer {
  width: 2520px;
}

.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider {
  float: left;
}
```

Here is [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jv8wqpst/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. Give your image and wrapper `width:100%` and `white-space:nowrap` to your wrapper

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://googleplus-covers.com/covers/nature_balloon_ride.jpg">
  <img src="http://p1.pichost.me/640/10/1326822.jpg">
  <img src="http://googleplus-covers.com/covers/coludy_mountains_nature.jpg">
</div>
```